# Why I get a compiler error (cannot cast from long to Long) on a TimeUnit to a date, while if i change the java compiler i don't get it anymore

Tags: java

I have this code, and on the last line compiler gives me error:
Cannot cast from long to Long.
If i change my java compiler, i uncheck the checkbox "Use compliance from execution enviroment CDC-1.1/Foundation.1-1 on the java BUild path" and i select a compliance compiler level 1.7 I don't get the error anymore? And there is a way to don't get that error don't changing java compiler compliance?

```
package data;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class DataProva {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();  

        cal2.set(2010,0,1,12,0);

        Date date1 = cal2.getTime();

        System.out.println(date1);  

        long mill = Math.abs(cal1.getTimeInMillis() - date1.getTime());


        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(mill);


        Long dayss = TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(hours); // here i get compiler error cannot cast from long to Long
```

Thank you so much!

EDIT:
I changed long dayss to Long because java changed it. I have still 2 question:
1) Why my java use such old version to compile.
2) Why the if i cast it like this:
   Long dayss = (Long) TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(hours);  doesn't work the same. How can i build a wrapper then in java 1.4

Each project i do start like this:
[image: mypic]

Comment: Does your code really not refer to `Long` anywhere? Because it looks *very* odd to me that you'd get this error anywhere...

Comment: `java 1.4` Isn't it too old version of JAVA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to continue to use Java 1.4 then replace this

```
Long dayss = TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(hours); // here i get compiler error cannot cast from long to Long
```

to this

```
Long dayss = Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(hours)); // here i get compiler error cannot cast from long to Long
```

Actually that is better coding practice no matter which version of java your using.

Comment: Because when casting it refers to the type that is being returned from the method to extend of class Object since a primitive doesn't extend Object class it can't be casted. see [link] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more information on casting.

Comment: Also in java all primitives types has an equal Class that extends Object. These classes all have the method valueOf(primitive)

Comment: Also take look at this to get a better understanding about primitive data types and their class counter part [link] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 3):

Java 1.5 adds a feature called auto-boxing, which implicitly converts between primitive types (like `long`) and boxed wrapper types (like `Long`).

Earlier versions do not have this feature, so you need to construct the wrapper types yourself.

Comment: That wasn't added in Java 1.7. It was in Java 1.5. (And it's not clear where `Long` would come in at all here, to be honest...)

Comment: Sorry, i correct code, java compiler automatically change it to long.
How can i constuct a wrapper tipe

Comment: @user3384514: In general, you shouldn't use the wrapper type.  Use `long`, not `Long`.